# How to insert captions to a Youtube video using the Youtube API v3?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to insert captions for a Youtube video using the Youtube API v3. Please note that I am not using any client library for this, only pure Node.js code.

When I make a request to this endpoint:

```
HTTP Method: POST
URL: https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/captions?part=id,snippet
Content-Type: "application/json"
Request Body: 
{
  "snippet": {
    "language": "en",
    "name": "Test",
    "videoId": "r6RMj7Y-NwL"
  }
}
```

I get this error **The request does not contain the caption track contents.** and that's clear because I have not uploaded any file, but how to upload it, it's not said how to do that in the Youtube API documentation https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions/insert

How the request should looks like to insert captions to Youtube video. Please help me.
It would be great if you could show how to do that using Node.js/Curl/Java/PHP without using client library

Comment: This has already been asked in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56931612/insert-caption-to-an-existing-video-youtube-api-error-the-request-does-not-con . I can just confirm it has not been answerd yet.